# Virtualbox Getting Blank Screen when Manjaro Installed?

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I'm using the latest version of Virtualbox to install Manjaro.

Everything works ok at first and I install Manjaro from the installer to the virtual machine.

But when I go to boot it (Choose **Boot Majaro on (hd0, something_here)** I only ever get a black screen.

Virtualization is enabled as confirmed by the BIOS.

EDIT 0: I'm using Kubunu 18.04LTS

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04LTS My bad.